# appending json data from one column to another using keys/ids

Tags: r

I have three tables like these that have a key and a field that describes that particular key's random data:

```
> json1
       key                                        field
1 hg8oxoi4 "components":{"a": "21","b": "12","c": "34"}
2 gic3bv14 "components":{"a": "78","b": "66","c": "54"}
3 yo47wglq  "components":{"a": "6","b": "12","c": "12"}
4 vibidd0l   "components":{"a": "45","b": "5","c": "1"}
> json2
       key                                          field
1 hg8oxoi4 "last_recall": {"date": "012118","size": "43"}
2 vibidd0l "last_recall": {"date": "101618","size": "12"}
> json3
       key                           field
1 hg8oxoi4 "other_fields":{"people": "11"}
2 gic3bv14 "other_fields":{"people": "10"}
3 yo47wglq  "other_fields":{"people": "4"}
```

whats the best way to combine all three tables into one, making sure to match all the keys to each other and deal with the differences in which keys have data and which don't? Ideally, each field would be appended onto the other so that the new table's field column is a json object with the different data.

Edit: Here's the expected output.

```
> json4
       key
1 hg8oxoi4
2 gic3bv14
3 yo47wglq
4 vibidd0l
                                                                                                                       field
1 {"components":{"a": "21","b": "12","c": "34"},"last_recall": {"date": "012118","size": "43"},"other_fields":{"people": "11"}}
2                                                {"components":{"a": "78","b": "66","c": "54"},"other_fields":{"people": "10"}}
3                                                  {"components":{"a": "6","b": "12","c": "12"},"other_fields":{"people": "4"}}
4                                   {"components":{"a": "45","b": "5","c": "1"},"last_recall": {"date": "101618","size": "12"}}
```

EDIT 2: dput of json1 and json2

```
> dput(json1)
structure(list(key = c("hg8oxoi4", "gic3bv14", "yo47wglq", "vibidd0l"
), field = c("\"components\":{\"a\": \"21\",\"b\": \"12\",\"c\": \"34\"}", 
"\"components\":{\"a\": \"78\",\"b\": \"66\",\"c\": \"54\"}", 
"\"components\":{\"a\": \"6\",\"b\": \"12\",\"c\": \"12\"}", 
"\"components\":{\"a\": \"45\",\"b\": \"5\",\"c\": \"1\"}")), .Names = c("key", 
"field"), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = "data.frame")

> dput(json2)
structure(list(key = c("hg8oxoi4", "vibidd0l"), field = c("\"last_recall\": {\"date\": \"012118\",\"size\": \"43\"}", 
"\"last_recall\": {\"date\": \"101618\",\"size\": \"12\"}")), .Names = c("key", 
"field"), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: can you post the `dput` of the `json1` and `json2`  Is it a character column.  Also, it is better to show the expected output

Comment: just added the expected output, all field columns are character columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We `merge` the datasets by 'key' after placing the 'datasets' in a `list`

```
out <- Reduce(function(...) merge(..., all = TRUE, by = "key"), 
       mget(ls(pattern ="^json\\d+$")))
```

Then, `paste` the non-NA elements rowwise

```
out$field <- apply(out[-1], 1, function(x) paste(x[!is.na(x)], collapse=", "))
out[c("key", "field")]
```

Comment: if I were to repeat this with differently named datasets (like test.df, field_store for example) would I use list(test.df,field_store) in place of your ls statement?

Comment: @aabernathy  You can use `list(test.df, field_store)`  The only reason I used `ls` is because of the pattern in the object names.  If there are 100 objects, it is more easy to do